# Secure web application in java using David Heffelfinger's book

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm trying to build a securewebapp as described in chapter 2 of David Heffelfinger's book 'Java EE 5 Development with NetBeans 6: Develop Professional Enterprise Java EE 5 Applications Quickly and Easily with this Popular IDE'. When following the last step (GlassFish-Specific Security Configuration), I tried to run the program. I get the following error message:

```java
deploy?DEFAULT=/home/bjorn/NetBeansProjects/securewebapp/build/web&name=securewebapp&contextroot=/securewebapp&force=true failed on GlassFish Server 3+ 
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [securewebapp] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 28; columnNumber: 57; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web].  cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'index.jsp' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '/.*' for type '#AnonType_war-pathType'.. Please see server.log for more details.
/home/bjorn/NetBeansProjects/securewebapp/nbproject/build-impl.xml:1033: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

The log-file shows:

```
SEVERE: DPL8015: Invalid Deployment Descriptors in Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web]. 
Line 28 Column 57 -- cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'index.jsp' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '/.*' for type '#AnonType_war-pathType'.
SEVERE: DPL8005: Deployment Descriptor parsing failure : cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'index.jsp' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '/.*' for type '#AnonType_war-pathType'.
SEVERE: Exception while deploying the app [securewebapp]
SEVERE: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 28; columnNumber: 57; Deployment descriptor file WEB-INF/web.xml in archive [web].  cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'index.jsp' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '/.*' for type '#AnonType_war-pathType'.
```

Does anybody know what to do to get the secure web application working?

**Edit:**

The file web.xml contains:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SecureServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>SecureServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SecureServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/SecureServlet</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Admin Pages</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Administrative Pages</web-resource-name>
            <description/>
            <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>file</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>index.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>errorpage.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
    <security-role>
        <description>Administrator</description>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-role>
        <description>User</description>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </security-role>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I have posted web.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `<login-config>` and put `/` in file paths.

```
<form-login-config>
    <form-login-page>/index.jsp</form-login-page>
    <form-error-page>/errorpage.jsp</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
```

**EDIT**: How **JAAS form based authentication** works?

The way form-based authentication works is that a user first tries to access a protected resource (like /admin/admin.jsp) from a publicly accessible resource file (like index.jsp or home.jsp) and if unauthenticated gets redirected to the `<form-login-page>` (like login.jsp).

The container at this point has saved the URL of the protected resource that the user was trying to access and ***automatically redirects*** to it if the authentication succeeds. If the authentication fails the user as you already know gets redirected to `<form-error-page>`.

So, I suggest you rename your index.jsp to login.jsp and create a new index.jsp with a link to /admin/admin.jsp. You can also try accessing the admin.jsp directly. It would then work as you want.

Comment: Thank you. Now the application runs. When I enter an incorrect password, I am directed to the errorpage, as I wish. But when I enter the correct username and password, I am redirected back to the login page (index.jsp). How can I enter the admin.jsp page when the correct password is given?

Comment: @user1189952 Comments added.

Comment: I tried the renaming but can't get it working. Do I have to change the url-pattern or the form-login-page?

Comment: Rename index.jsp to login.jsp and update `<form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>` to reflect that. Then access /admin/admin.jsp directly or through a link inside a new index.jsp.

Comment: When I do this I get the following message on a webpage: HTTP Status 404 -

type Status report

message

descriptionThe requested resource () is not available.

Comment: Please use the complete path when using the browser. I think your app is named `securewebapp` so your URL becomes `http://localhost/securewebapp/admin/admin.jsp`

Comment: When I try to use the complete URL the application is not built at all. When I try to use <url-pattern>/admin.jsp</url-pattern> I keep on being redirected to http://localhost:8080/securewebapp/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29135/discussion-between-ravi-and-user1189952)